# In the U.S., what is the exact process by which a Citizen proposes an idea for a bill to their Senator or Representative?

Tags: united-states, legislative-process

## Background (unrelated to question, but it is what lead me to ask the question)

My SO and I were talking about an alternative solution to how Senators are elected other than through direct popular vote. She brought up the idea of a mini-electoral college per state, as opposed to appointment by state legislature (which is what it was before the 17th amendment).  Moreover, she posited that the drafting body for each State's Electoral College could be impaneled like a jury. I was intrigued by this proposal and wanted to send something to my reps about this idea.  However, I am unsure about how exactly to do this at the federal level. This lead me to ask...

## Question

If I have an idea for Federal bill, how exactly do I send this idea to my Federal Representatives?

Comment: https://medium.com/k-street/how-to-form-a-super-pac-political-action-committee-99595e5304ab

Comment: I would edit myself, but I'm not sure whether you prefer "this leads me to ask" or "this led me to ask."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traditionally, you would write a letter to their office or call them by phone.  You can still do that, of course, but you can now also send e-mail.  Some even have contact forms that allow you to send a message on the web page.

You can find your representative's office at

https://www.house.gov/representatives/find-your-representative

The analogous page for senators is

https://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm

Comment: The most effective way is to funnel huge wads of cash in the direction of said elected representative.